# Use result from MongoDB in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass the results from a MongoDB query to use in a Javascript file in my view. I am using handlebars as my view engine. My MongoDB schema is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
    lat: {type: String},
    lng: {type: String},
    classes: [{
        day: String,
        start: String,
        end: String
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dojo', schema);
```

My routing file has the following:

```
router.get('/classes', function(req, res, next) {
  Dojo.find(function(err, dojos) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    res.render('admin/classes', {
      layout: 'layout-admin.hbs',
      title: 'Admin',
      js: 'classes-admin',
      dojos: dojos
    });
  });
});
```

Within my hbs file, I have:

```
<p>{{ dojos }}</p>
```

The code above shows my variable on the screen OK but when I try to console.log this within script tags I get an Uncaught SyntaxError. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log({{ dojos }});
</script>
```

Any advice on where I'm going wrong would be great appreciated.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try to change script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mongo_result = {{dojos}};
    console.log({{ mongo_result }});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Galkin but it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to EJS as my template engine and used `var dojos = <%- JSON.stringify(dojos) %>;` which worked great.